# Is there a way to trigger ValuesChange or Change event on Form.Item in Ant Design Form

Tags: antd

I have three Form.Item: Country, Province, City. City depends on Province that depends on Country. When Country is changed, I'll update Province with form.setFieldsValue, and then I'd like to trigger Change event on Province, which automatically calls onChange event handler and updates City. Is there a way to trigger Change event on Province?

Antd form offers dependencies https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item, but it seems to only work to automatically validate. Please let me know if you have any ideas, thank you!